# как подключить dll к c# проекту

Tags: c#, .net

Есть dll файл, как импортировать его в проект? Можно ли добавить dll как полноценный объект, а не вызываемые методы?

Comment: dll какой? нативный или управляемый? в чем именно проблема?

Comment: как определить нативный или управляемы? проблема в том, что не знаю как его импортировать в проект

Comment: подключить в проект можно только другой проект. Управляемую C# библиотеку можно подключить как сборку. Из неуправляемой можно ссылаться только на методы через `[DllImport]`, то есть P/Invoke. Хотите из них класс получить - создайте класс и поместите туда импорты. Есть еще система COM, но это уже другая длинная история.

Comment: dll идет как библиотека. "Управляемую C# библиотеку можно подключить как сборку" - можно гайд, не могу найти

Comment: Класс `Assembly` умеет загружать C# библиотки.

Comment: Можно еще ссылку на dll сборку в csproj файле прописать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если dll файл это .net сборка, то можно на него добавить ссылку в Visual Studio так: в обозревателе решений: зависимости -> Добавить ссылку на проект -> Обзор -> Обзор.